# Ecto conditional upsert - Ecto.StaleEntryError

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to accomplish smart upsert, which I define as:

- if there is no model with same id in db do INSERT
- if there is entry with same id in db and that entry is newer (updated_at field) do NOT UPDATE
- if there is entry with same id in db and that entry is older (updated_at field) do UPDATE

I see that repo.insert has option to pass query as `:on_conflict` option.
I decided to write minimalistic source code that meets my needs.

```
update_query =
  from s in User,
     where: s.id == ^id,
     where: s.updated_at < ^updated_at,
     update: ^[set: Map.to_list(data)]

%User{}
|> Ecto.Changeset.change(data)
|> @repo.insert(conflict_target: :id, on_conflict: update_query)
```

This code works only if insert is happening. On conflict it results in `(Ecto.StaleEntryError) attempted to insert a stale struct:` error. I can remove `where: s.id == ^id, where: s.updated_at < ^updated_at` from update_query and remove this error, however then I lose the desired updated_at check.
Desired postgres code would look like

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, entry) VALUES (42, '2021-05-29 12:00:00')
ON CONFLICT (id)
   DO UPDATE SET entry = EXCLUDED.entry, ......
      WHERE mytable.entry < EXCLUDED.entry;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this "problem" just now, and with a bit of sleuthing, found that the `Ecto.StaleEntryError` happens because the condition means there is no row to update. The article at https://subvisual.com/blog/posts/145-upsert-statements-with-ecto/ mostly helped figure this out for me.

I had to remove the `where: s.id == ^id` clause from the update condition – since that's already a given from running within the insert context – and also add to the `insert` the following clauses:

```
stale_error_field: :updated_at,
stale_error_message: "is out of date"
```

So I did something like:

```
cs = changeset(%Data{}, data)
Repo.insert(cs,
  conflict_target: :id,
  on_conflict:
    from(d in Data,
      where: d.updated_at < ^updated_at,
      update: [set: ^Map.to_list(cs.changes)]
    ),
  stale_error_field: :updated_at,
  stale_error_message: "is out of date"
)
```

This allows me to run the insert, which returns the error changeset when trying to insert something that's too old:

```
%Ecto.Changeset{errors: [updated_at: {"is out of date", [stale: true]}]}
```

And this you can then easily handle in your surrounding code. You might want to log something about receiving out of date updates, for example.

(A small additional thing I had to do was ensure that `updated_at` was never `nil`, since otherwise the `from` condition won't work, complaining that `comparison with nil is forbidden as it is unsafe`.)

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be easier to do something like the following:

```
def smart_upsert(%{id: id, updated_at: updated_at} = data) do
    query =
      from u in User,
      where: u.id == ^id,
      where: u.updated_at < ^updated_at
     
    User
    |> Repo.get_by(query)
    |> case do
      nil ->
        %User{}

      existing_user ->
        existing_user
    end
    |> User.changeset(data)
    |> Repo.insert_or_update()
  end
```

This admittedly requires 2 database operations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know this approach but I'm trying to avoid that as well as dig a little deeper on how I can leverage Ecto.